# Having trouble generating a SOAP RPC envelope from a WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

We are generating a SOAP envelope using WSDL4J to parse the WSDL and XSOM to parse the schema (to find the types). This works fine with "Document" web services but not with "RPC" style services.

When parsing RPC style we receive errors stating that the parser is unable to reference types in other namespaces (from the `wsdl:definition` and not inside the schema)